# Variable with multiple values to use

Tags: variables, lua, fivem

Im editing a script for fivem and Im trying to store multiple values into a variable then using an if statement to see if a player has one of the values in his inventory. So far i have this

`Config.ItemVapeLiquid = 'liquid', 'liquidice', 'liquidberry'`

the problem I'm having is it only runs when the player has 'liquid' on them, when they don't, it returns a nil value even if they have 'liquidice' or 'liquidberry'. what im trying to get do is:

```
Config.ItemVapeLiquid = 'liquid', 'liquidice', 'liquidberry'

if the player has a value from ItemVapeLiquid then
  allow player to add liquid
```

I want it to check all the values in the variable before returning nil as it seems to be checking 1 value and returning nil if its not in the inventory

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the first line compiles, it will ignore any unassigned values (`'liquidice'`, `'liquidberry'`).

It expects three variables:

```lua
local a, b, c = 'liquid', 'liquidice', 'liquidberry'
```

Since that's impractical you need an array instead, as well as a function to search within that array:

```lua
Config.ItemVapeLiquid = {'liquid', 'liquidice', 'liquidberry'}

function check(array, value)
    for _,v in ipairs(array) do
        if v == value then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

print(check(Config.ItemVapeLiquid, 'liquid'))
print(check(Config.ItemVapeLiquid, 'liquidice'))
print(check(Config.ItemVapeLiquid, 'liquidberry'))
print(check(Config.ItemVapeLiquid, 'something'))
```

```lua
true
true
true
false
```

If you plan on calling checks more often, consider transforming the array into a set instead, since this is much faster:

```lua
-- feel free to make an array-to-set function for this
Config.ItemVapeLiquid = {
    ['liquid'] = true,
    ['liquidice'] = true,
    ['liquidberry'] = true
}

print(Config.ItemVapeLiquid['liquid'])
print(Config.ItemVapeLiquid['liquidice'])
print(Config.ItemVapeLiquid['liquidberry'])
print(Config.ItemVapeLiquid['something'])
```

```
true
true
true
nil
```

Notice that a missing element is now nil, which evaluates to false and is therefore usually fine. If you really need a false value, append:

```lua
Config.ItemVapeLiquid["something"] or false
```